# Scope of public method in private class in java - no package

Tags: java, scope

I have encapsulated variables in a private data class inside of a public data structure, if I have a public method in the private class, what can access that method?

If I have a class that can access the private object through a get method in the public class can the first object access the public get or set method in the private class?

If you need any other information please let me know.

Comment: There is nothing like "private" top level class, however you can have "private" inner class, but need to give more clarity on what are doing and thinking.

Comment: It's still a bit unclear what the problem is - you should try to explain it using a small (pseudo-)code example

Comment: What happened when you coded up an example and tried it, @Ben Stumpf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anything with access to the `private` member type will have access to its `public` members in turn.

Comment: I think the scenario is that the class is private but the instance is made available through a public getter.

Comment: The instance can't be made available if the type is `private` except through an accessible supertype.

Comment: Well... the getter will compile, you just can't call it outside the class.